# Why wouldn't a DataGridView show the Databound values?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I've got a moderately complex situation, where I've got a parent-child relationship set up with a bunch of `BindingSource`s, so I've got:

```
DisposalBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(MyLibrary.Disposal);

DisposalCertificateBindingSource.DataMember = "DisposalCertificates";
DisposalCertificateBindingSource.DataSource = this.DisposalBindingSource;

AssetDisposalBindingSource.DataMember = "AssetDisposals";
AssetDisposalBindingSource.DataSource = this.DisposalBindingSource;
```

This is where `MyLibrary.Disposal` looks a little like:

```
public class Disposal
{
    private EntitySet<AssetDisposal> _certificates;
    public ICollection<AssetDisposal> AssetDisposals
    {
        get
        {
            if (_certificates == null)
            {
                _certificates = new EntitySet<AssetDisposal>();
                _certificates.SetSource(AssetDisposal.Search(this)); // return value happens to be BindingList<AssetDisposal>; Use SetSource so that ListChangedEvents fire correctly.
            }

            return _certificates;
        }
    }

    private EntitySet<DisposalCertificate> _certificates;
    public ICollection<DisposalCertificate> DisposalCertificates
    {
        get
        {
            if (_certificates == null)
            {
                _certificates = new EntitySet<DisposalCertificate>();
                _certificates.SetSource(DisposalCertificate.Search(this)); // return value happens to be BindingList<DisposalCertificate>; Use SetSource so that ListChangedEvents fire correctly.
            }

            return _certificates;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, both of the child `BindingSource`s are used on `DataGridView`s on different tabs of a `TabControl`, but what I don't understand is why the `DataGridView` that uses `AssetDisposalBindingSource` works, but the one that uses the `DisposalCertificateBindingSource` (which is not on the active tab on load) does not?

By not working, both grids show the correct number of rows, and the `DataBoundItem` is what I'd expect, but the columns in the grid don't show anything. What might be causing this to not show the values from the data bound items?

Not sure if it's related, but the designer does insist on adding columns for the `Count` and `IsReadOnly` properties of each `EntitySet<T>`.

Comment: What if you swap the `DisposalCertificateBindingSource` to be bound to the active tab on load? Does that works? I'm asking this question as you explicitly said (which is not on the active tab on load).

Comment: I've never seen typeof for a DataSource before: `DisposalBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(MyLibrary.Disposal);`. Is that something entity related?

Comment: @LarsTech One usage is: For untyped binding sources like `BindingSource`, if you set the `DataSource` to `typeof(Something)` binding frameworks will be able to read the metadata of the type before adding elements to it. For instance when using `DataGridView` `AutoGenerateColumns`, without `BindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Something)` columns will not be generated if the list is empty.

Comment: @LarsTech it's also the code generated if you use the designer to create the `BindingSource`

Comment: how it does not work? the datagrid shows the colums but no rows(no data) or all blank?...if all blank maybe a long shot but check how you wrote the data member string...

Comment: @terrybozzio "By not working, both grids show the correct number of rows, and the DataBoundItem is what I'd expect, but the columns in the grid don't show anything."

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this turned out to be something really stupid - the property I was trying to bind was `private`. Setting the the property to `public` resolved the issue.